# Proving Matrix Lie Groups are Lie Groups without using Lie Algebras

Tags: lie-groups, topological-groups, linear-groups

As the title suggests, I'm wondering if there are any proofs that Matrix Lie Groups (defined as closed subgroups of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$) are Lie Groups that do not require the use of Lie algebras. I'm aware of the general proofs owed to von Neumann and Cartan, however, these require Lie algebras and I would like to avoid using that due to the scope of the project I am working on. I have been advised to look at "Lessons of differentiable geometry" by Postnikov. However, I cannot find a proof in there that does not require Lie Algebras. Is such a proof possible?

Comment: Is using the exponential map and its properties fine? If so, I think you'll find the standard proof of the closed subgroup theorem doesn't involve Lie algebras in any essential way; the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ is simply being used as a convenient label for $T_eG$ (in your case the sapce on $n\times n$ matrices).